# Questions about getting a job

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to post questions, in SO’s main site, about getting a job? Or is there a different place for that?

My question is more so in the angle of all the technologies I know and find out where to go, why I’m lacking in the industry, and how to move up in the field. I don’t know if questions of this kind are permitted, so I wanted to make sure.

Thanks

Comment: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Also, personal career advice is often too localized since it seldom helps other.

Comment: I would recommend following a training course to get help with setting up your resume, getting tips on how to approach companies and how to present yourself well, etc.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com might be a better match.